# Guardar datos en un estado antes de que renderee el componente

Tags: reactjs

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es renderizar un componente que dentro tiene otro componente de Google Maps y como parametros le tengo que pasar la latitud y longitud que viene de mi base de datos en Mongoose, mi codigo es el siguiente

```js
    async componentWillMount() {
        await Axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/restaurants/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            .then(resp => {
                this.setState({ datos: resp.data });
                this.setState({ menu: resp.data.menu });
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Y lo que tengo en mi render es.

```js
render(){
{ console.log(this.state.datos) }
return (
<div className="mapa">
      <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={16}
          initialCenter={{ lat: this.state.datos.latitud, lng: this.state.datos.longitud }}
      >
          <Marker
              position={{ lat: 19.437201, lng: -99.200885 }} />
      </Map>
</div>
)}
```

Si pongo los valores manualmente si me renderea bien el componente , pero si hago que sea desde la base de datos no me genera nada ya que al primer momento que renderea el componente, el estado está vacio y luego lo renderea como si no tuviera nada y luego que ya aparecen los datos no se vuelve a renderear ese componente, lo que sale en consola es lo siguiente.

1. []
2. {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
3. {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

Como se puede ver, al primer momento está vacío y luego se renderea ese componente.

Comment: Sería bueno saber de donde viene tu componente `Map` y de qué forma estás renderizando en el otro componente el mapa, así te podríamos ofrecer más ayuda

Comment: @GermanAlzate, la verdad no sabría, ya que es un componente externo que lo jalo al hacer npm i google-maps-react

Comment: Bueno a ese tipo de información me refiero, a el origen del componente, en este caso `google-maps-react`. Por ahora lo que veo es que el parámetro que atacas se llama `initialCenter` lo cual a simple vista solo por el nombre indica que es algo que solo llamará una vez al *iniciar* por lo que seguramente cuando tu servidor trae los datos este no los toma en cuenta. Deberías intentar atacar otro prop, o hacer como te dicen en la respuesta, la cual sería la idea, no renderizar hasta tener los datos

Comment: Leyendo la documentación, podrías predefinir un `initialCenter` y más bien setear los datos que vienen de tu servidor en el prop `center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías tener un control para saber cuando los datos están listos para mostrar el mapa:

```
  render() {
    const {datos } = this.state;

    if (!datos) { // mostramos al user que está cargando y devolvemos un loading
      return <span>Cargando...</span>
    }

    return ( // mostramos el mapa cuando haya datos
      <Componentemap {...{datos} />
    )
  }
```

Te recomiendo no usar `componentWillMount`, ya que está deprecado. Deberías usar componentDidMount.

Recuerda que setState se mergea, por lo cual podes hacer:

```
this.setState({
  datos: resp.data,
  menu: resp.data.menu
});
```

en vez de

```
this.setState({ datos: resp.data });
this.setState({ menu: resp.data.menu });
```

También estás guardando menu dos veces en el estado, que puede llevar a bugs si se leen y actualizan en distintos lados en tu aplicación.